# Scrobble shoutcast station on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any player/plugin/hack that works on Ubuntu and would scrobble "now playing" info from shoutcast radio station ID3 tags to last.fm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I needed to perform similar operations in Windows some time ago I used Winamp with StreamRipper plugin. I think there should be some similar programs for Linux available.

The methodology requires some program to rip (and tag) the shoutcast stream and append the tracks to music player's que from where they get scrobbled as ordinary pieces.

Comment: Yeah, that's a solution -- hackish and brittle but works:
 * streamripper is also available on linux,
 * set up automatic playlist in Rhythmbox with 4 rules:
 ** Only songs from streamripper dump directory
 ** No songs from "incomplete" subdirectory
 ** Only songs added to library in last hour
 ** Only songs with play count = 0

Answer (score 0):

[Songbird](http://getsongbird.com) can probably do that, I'm not 100% sure, but it scobbles and can play shoutcast radio (both of these via an addon) Its not sure this will work, but its worth a shot. there are songbird .debs out there, a quick google search will find them.

Comment: Will give it a shot. 
Although by the same token, Rhythmbox also can both play stations and scrobble, but it has explicit checks in code not to scrobble podcasts, short tracks, etc. Also, Rhythmbox scrobbles on "song change" event, but radio stations don't generate these.